# Why is View not reloading?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I want to reload TvrPrnetExcel with CopytoAPResults method but the view is not redirect to Action. I tried to use another action. It didn't work. Method is working, however redirecting is not working. Why? What should I do?:

Here is my Action:

```html
  public ActionResult TvrPrnetExcel()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> TvrPrnetExcel(FormCollection form)
        {

.........

            using (var db = new TVREntities()){
            

            foreach (string i in ids)
            {
                    var dataID = Convert.ToInt64(i);
                    TVRClip tvrClip = db.TVRClip.Where(x => x.TVRClipDataID == dataID).SingleOrDefault();
                    TVRPublicationProgram publicationProgram = db.TVRPublicationProgram.Where(x => x.TVRProgramID == tvrClip.TVRProgramID).FirstOrDefault();


                        using (var db2 = new MpnetContext())
                        {
                            tbl_APVideoResults APVideoResults = db2.tbl_APVideoResults.Where(x => x.APClipId == dataID).FirstOrDefault();
                            if (APVideoResults != null && APVideoResults.WMVFile != null)
                            {
                                pr.wmvFile = APVideoResults.WMVFile.ToString();
                            }
                            else 
                            {
                                nonexist.Add(dataID);
                                pr.wmvFile = "";
                            }

                        }
                           
                    pr.haberLink = "http://www.prnet.com.tr/wmv/" + pr.tarih.Substring(0, 2) + pr.tarih.Substring(3, 2) + pr.tarih.Substring(6, 4) + pr.wmvFile + ".mp4";
                    tVRClips.Add(pr);
      


            }
            }

            Task t1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                CopytoAPResults(nonexist, form);
            });

            return View(tVRClips);
        }
```

Here is my method.

```html
            private ActionResult CopytoAPResults(List<long> nonexist, FormCollection form)
            {

                if (nonexist.Count()>0)
                { 
                foreach (long i in nonexist){ }
                    
                }

                return RedirectToAction("TvrPrnetExcel");
            }
```

Comment: Why are you calling `CopytoAPResults` **from a new `Task`** and then **ignoring the return value**? If you always execute `return View(tVRClips);` (which you do) then you **aren't redirecting**.

Comment: I want to send `tvrClips` to view firstly. By the way I want to run `CopytoAPResults` method and when that method finished, object will be sent to view again. Because working of method is taking long time.

Comment: That isn't how MVC works. You can't return a `View` and then 'hope' that a redirect is magically sent afterwards. A request can return only one thing (a view **or** a request, not both).

Answer (score -1):

Change this :

```
   Task t1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        CopytoAPResults(nonexist, form);
    });

    return View(tVRClips);
```

To Simply :

```
        Task t1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            return CopytoAPResults(nonexist, form);
        });
```

As CopytoAPResults Includes the redirect and the redirect after that should never be reached.

Comment: You didn't understand me. I want to send model to view firstly. By the way I want to run another method and when that method finished, model will be sent to view again.

Comment: You can only send one model/class to a view. Sorry for misunderstanding what you wan't. I don't think what you are trying to achieve is possible.